# Change Monodevelop background colour in Ubuntu

Tags: background, ubuntu-12.04, monodevelop

This is not a technical question but a question about ease of usage of an IDE.

I have recently started Monodevelop(Ver 5.9.4) in Linux(Ubuntu).
The issue I face is that the coding window is white and its stress-full for my eyes as I am used to code in darker backgrounds. How can I change it?

Please help. I have looked other places but I am not convinced.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit > Preferences >  Syntax Highlighting

This wouldn't change everything in the GUI, but it will change the part where you are staring at the code to black background.